# How can I return the property values of a nested JavaScript array nested in an object from JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, functional-programming, javascript-objects

Given a JS array containing many objects which all contain arrays:

```
var data = [ 
   {id: 1, name: "Fred", pages:[{url:"www.abc.com", title: "abc"}]}, 
   {id: 2, name: "Wilma", pages:[{url:"www.123.com", title: "123"}]}, 
   {id: 3, name: "Pebbles", pages:[{url:"www.xyz.com", title: "xyz"}]}
];
```

How do I efficiently extract the inner most array (pages) values into an array?

```
var dataArray = [
    {url: "www.abc.com", title: "abc"}, 
    {url: "www.123.com", title: "123"}, 
    {url: "www.xyz.com", title: "xyz"}
    ]
```

Comment: use array `map()` method. check my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"? Where are you stuck with this? Do you have a problem with how to loop over `data`? Do you have a problem with how to retrieve/access the `pages` property from each element in `data`? Do you have a problem with how to retrieve/access the first element from each element in `pages`?

Comment: Can `pages` have multiple elements, and if so do you want all of them in the result, or just the first one?

Comment: Where I was getting stuck is getting url and id from each pages array without knowing the size of the data set. Pages can have any number of elements per array - in this case I only want to return url and title which could be in any order in the pages array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use `Array#map` like so:

```
var dataArray = data.map(function(o){return o.pages});
```

If `pages` is an array of objects (not a single object), this will result in an array of arrays, which you will need to flatten out for example using `Array#reduce`:

```
dataArray = dataArray.reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b)}, []);
```

Comment: you could combine the two operations like `var dataArray = data.map(function(o){return o.pages}).reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b)}, []);`

Comment: I think your `reduce` is a wordy version of `[].concat(...dataArray)`.

Comment: @torazaburo sure that's another way to do it, but uses `...` from ES6, ES5 equivalent: `Array.prototype.concat.apply([],dataArray)`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `flatMap`

```js
var data = [ 
   {id: 1, name: "Fred", pages:[{url:"www.abc.com", title: "abc"}]}, 
   {id: 2, name: "Wilma", pages:[{url:"www.123.com", title: "123"}]}, 
   {id: 3, name: "Pebbles", pages:[{url:"www.xyz.com", title: "xyz"}]}
];

const concat = (xs, ys) => xs.concat(ys);

const prop = x => y => y[x];

const flatMap = (f, xs) => xs.map(f).reduce(concat, []);

console.log(
  flatMap(prop('pages'), data)
);
```

Comment: Very nice except for the missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example on how to achieve what you want:

```
var data = [ 
   {id: 1, name: "Fred", pages:[{url:"www.abc.com", title: "abc"}, {url:"www.google.com", title: "Google"}]}, 
   {id: 2, name: "Wilma", pages:[{url:"www.123.com", title: "123"}]}, 
   {id: 3, name: "Pebbles", pages:[{url:"www.xyz.com", title: "xyz"}]}
];

var arr = Array();
var arr2 = Array();

// You can either iterate it like this:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // If you only want the first page in your result, do:
  // arr.push(data[i].pages[0]);

  // If you want all pages in your result, you can iterate the pages too:
  for (var a = 0; a < data[i].pages.length; a++) {
    arr.push(data[i].pages[a]);
  }
}

// Or use the array map method as suggested dtkaias 
// (careful: will only work on arrays, not objects!)
//arr2 = data.map(function (o) { return o.pages[0]; });

// Or, for all pages in the array:
arr2 = [].concat(...data.map(function (o) { return o.pages; }));

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
// Returns 2x [Object { url="www.abc.com",  title="abc"}, Object { url="www.123.com",  title="123"}, Object { url="www.xyz.com",  title="xyz"}]
```

Comment: but it still wrong, what if there will be several page objects in pages key?

Comment: That was not the question. The question was how it specifically works with the given array structure. If there are multiple keys, we first need more information on how these should be chained, right?

Comment: The `pages` properties in the input didn't contain multiple objects in the example, but it is "pages" with an "s" and it is an array, so it's not unreasonable to think that sometimes there will be more than one page per `id` something like `pages:[{url:"www.abc.com", title: "abc"}, {url:"www.def.com", title: "def"}, {url:"www.ghi.com", title: "ghi"}]`

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to loop over arrays with `for...in`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: But you'll have to agree that this is just an assumption by you as well. The OP explained that she wants a return array with just one object per item. Without further information this code is what does exactly that, even if there are multiple "pages" in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If by "efficiently" you actually mean "concisely", then

```
[].concat(...data.map(elt => elt.pages))
```

The `data.map` will result in an array of `pages` arrays. The `[].concat(...` then passes all the `pages` arrays as parameters to `concat`, which will combine all of their elements into a single array.

If you are programming in ES5, the equivalent would be

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], data.map(function(elt) { return elt.pages; }))
```

Answer (score 0):

**use array [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method :**

```js
var data = [ 
   {id: 1, name: "Fred", pages:[{url:"www.abc.com", title: "abc"}]}, 
   {id: 2, name: "Wilma", pages:[{url:"www.123.com", title: "123"}]}, 
   {id: 3, name: "Pebbles", pages:[{url:"www.xyz.com", title: "xyz"}]}
];
    
var dataArray = data.map(function(item) {
  return item.pages;
});    

dataArray = dataArray.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);

console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: Yes, but only if the OP wants only the first element in each of the `pages` array--we'll have to let her tell us if that is the case.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer.